# How to restore/reuse json serialized objects in fabricjs?

Tags: json, socket.io, fabricjs

I am trying to create a collaborative whiteboard with socket.io and fabric.js.

When a user draws something I send the path to other users as a JSON format:

```
canvas.on('path:created', function(e) {
  canvas.remove(fabric.Path.fromObject(JSON.stringify(e.path)));
  socket.emit('add path', e.path.toJSON());
});
```

How can I recreate this object on the canvas here?

```
socket.on('add path', function(path) {
  canvas.add(path); // doesn't work
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use `fabric.util.enlinvenObjects`

The purpouse of that function is to switch from object form to istance.

```
socket.on('add path', function(path) {
  fabric.util.enlivenObjects([path], function(objects) {
    objects.forEach(function(o) {
      canvas.add(o);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! However, the same path (in json format) doesn't work with `canvas.remove()`, how would you remove a path from json format?

Comment: canvas.remove(fabric.Path.fromObject(JSON.stringify(e.path)));  you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

For those calling this function in a TypeScript project...
In my case setting `namespace` to empty string (`''`) and explicitly typing the callback argument made the function work smoothly.

```js
fabric.util.enlivenObjects(
        action.payload.objects,
        (enlivedObjects: fabric.Object[]) => {
          canvas.add(...enlivedObjects);
          canvas.renderAll();
        },
'');
```